# single CASE for multiple columns data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Item with quantity and price are queried from SQL server for Excel and Crystal Report.  The quantity and price are bulk quantity (pounds).  I need to convert it to bag quantity and bag price.  Pounds per bag data is not in SQL server and it is different on each item.  My item is around 20 only.  I cannot create permanent or temporary table to store pounds per bag data in SQL Server.  I can use CASE in SQL to calculate bag quantity and price.  But, it needs two CASEs.  How can I use one CASE or other method which can simplify the SQL and keep it simple to maintain?  My current SQL.

```
SELECT Item, Quantity, Price, 
CASE item
    WHEN ‘Item1’ THEN Quantity/32
    WHEN ‘Item2’ THEN Quantity/33
    …
    ELSE Quantity
END AS QtyPerBag,
CASE item
    WHEN ‘Item1’ THEN Price*32
    WHEN ‘Item2’ THEN Quantity*33
    …
    ELSE Price
END AS PricePerBag
FROM MasterTable
```

Comment: *Pounds per bag data is not in SQL server and it is different on each item*. Try to load this data into a table. Then the query will be much shorter and easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DhruvJoshi's approach is a good approach.  Using the `VALUES()` constructor, it is even simpler:

```
SELECT mt.Item, mt.Quantity, mt.Price,
       mt.Quantity/factors.Factor AS QtyPerBag, 
       Price * Factors.factor AS PricePerBag
FROM MasterTable mt LEFT JOIN 
     (VALUES ('Item1', 32), ('Item2', 33)
     ) factors(item, factor)
     ON factors.item = mt.item;
```

Note:  If you quantity is stored as an integer, then you should use decimal points for the factors (unless you want integer division).

Comment: Both solutions from Gordon Linoff and DhruvJoshi help a lots.  It solve my problem while Gordon Linoff's solution is neat.

Comment: Answers like this is what makes SQL so fun!

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in comments you should consider using table/set approach.

One way if you want to do that inside of a query is like below:

```
SELECT Item, Quantity, Price, Quantity/Factor AS QtyPerBag, 
Price * Factor AS PricePerBag
FROM MasterTable LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT 'Item1' as Item, '32' as Factor 
UNION 
SELECT 'Item2' as Item, '33' as Factor 
-- and so on ...
) T
ON T.item=masterTable.item
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  I do not have privilege to load this data into SQL Server table.

Comment: @YellowLarry I guessed so. I'm glad the query helped you.